# High & Low Level graphics in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I wann to know what is the difference between high & low level graphics 
And what is the use of both ....

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 2):

High-level graphics is handled by the device itself (its implementation, to be more precise). Low-level graphics require you to draw it manually, but you are in full control of what will be displayed to the user.

Talking about Java ME almost everything in `javax.microedition.lcdui` package is related to high-level graphics. Low-level graphics is handled by `Canvas` and `Graphics` and also by the classes inside the `javax.microedition.lcdui.game` package.

The advantage of the high-level graphics is that it's very easy to use, since you are not required to draw anyhing by hand, so it's perfect to create UI fast. The disadvantage is that you are limited to the elements in MIDP 2.0 (the only extension possibiility is `CustomItem`) and you can't control how the elements are drawn. Low-level graphics allows you to draw anything on the screen, but it requires a lot of work to create a good UI manually.

Games typically use mostly low-level graphics, other applications use only high-level graphics or both. By the way, there are some alternatives like [LWUIT](http://java.sun.com/javame/technology/lwuit/), it is a library that uses low-level graphics to create UI.